# Variable inside selector - jQuery - this is tricky

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function:

```
function ConditionalMake( $makeselector, $modelselector ) {
 // my code in here
}
```

I am initializing my function like this:

```
var make_selector = $('select#make');
var model_selector = $('select#model');
ConditionalMake( make_selector, model_selector );
```

How can I use a variable inside a selector like this (obviously this does not work):

```
var chosen = $makeselector + 'option:selected'.text();
```

When using my function without this variable it works fine, such as:

```
$('select#make option:selected').text();
```

How do I add 'option:selected' to my selector which is already a variable which is a selector (hope that makes sense)?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Note that if you are selecting by element ID you don't need to include the element type in the selector. So use `$('#make')` instead of `$('select#make')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, all you need is the `find` function:

```
var chosen = $makeselector.find('option:selected').text();
```

Alternatively, you can use `.children()`.  But this may not work because it only searches immediate children of the current element.

```
var chosen = $makeselector.children('option:selected').text();
```

Comment: Oh wow that was easy, lol! Thanks so much I knew it would be something simple - works perfect :) I will mark this as the correct answer when I can in 10 minutes. Cheers.